# PHP run a java program and get the output

Tags: javascript, java, php

I have PHP that I am running with ajax. What I want to happen is the php executes a java program returns the output of said java program. Right now in my PHP file, as a test I am trying

```
exec("java -version", $output);
print_r($output);
```

However, this just prints to the console

```
Array
(
)
```

Also, when I add in my actual java program, it is outputting using System.out.println() if that makes a difference as to how it is read by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As it states in http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php, you should:

```
$output = shell_exec('java -version');
print_r($output);
```

Comment: That just outputs an empty line.

Comment: Ok, try this: print_r(shell_exec('echo 111')); What would it output ?

Comment: @CameronK , ok, now run "java -version" in terminal without any additional environment changes. Just open new terminal window and run this command. What would it output?

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Did you run php code through php-cli, or through some kind of web server (apache, phpfpm) ?

Comment: Im using apache

Comment: @CameronK so, it is possible, that your apache user (usually www-data) don't have access to run java -version.

Comment: How would I fix this? If it helps my server is on a raspberry pi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161951/discussion-between-mihanentalpo-and-cameron-k).